# Inquire the usage of article in this context

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles

I am writing an academic paper and confused about the following usage of "a/an":

> with an MAP score below 0.4

Or

> with a MAP score below 0.4

While the second one seems more "grammarly" correct, I see frequent usage of the first one. Indeed, if you Google `an mAP` with Google Scholar, you will find plenty of usages in research papers.

So, which one is more correct? Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Never mind "grammarly". The rule has to do with pronunciation, not grammar. If the speaker pronounces _MAP_ as /ɛmeipi/ then it starts with a vowel and _an_ is appropriate. If, on the other hand, the speaker says _MAP_ as /mæp/, then it starts with a consonant and _a_ is appropriate. But you have to know how it's pronounced.

Comment: @JohnLawler  thanks for the comment. So basically, the `mAP` stands for `mean Average Precision`, a term frequently used in Computer Vision research. In that sense, maybe the second option is more reasonable?

Comment: It doesn't matter what it stands for; it only matters how you **pronounce** it, by letters or by acronym, and that's random. So, how do **you** pronounce it? And, if you're writing, how do your **readers** pronounce it? If you don't know, find out.

Comment: @JohnLawler. I got your point!! Thanks a lot. I will pronounce it as `/ɛmeipi/`.

Comment: In which case, 'an' is more appropriate.